# Spring boot AOP aspect causes autwired beans to return null

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, autowired

Using the `@Around` annotation to define an aspect causes the autowiring of the bean to return null. I know this has something to do with some kind of proxy that aspectj sets up, and that this might be resolved via a few annotations. I just don't know what those annotations are, nor do I know whwere to put them. This only happens with the @Around aspects, not with @Before or @After.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AopStuffApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private Business1 business1;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AopStuffApplication.class.getName());

    public AopStuffApplication() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AopStuffApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info(business1.calculateSomething());
    }
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class Business1 {

    @Autowired
    private Dao1 dao1;

    public String calculateSomething() {
        return dao1.retrieveSomething();
    }
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public class Dao1 {

    public String retrieveSomething() {
        System.out.println("Inside of retrieveSomething().");
        return "Dao1";
    }
}
```

---

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MethodExecutionCalculationAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MethodExecutionCalculationAspect.class.getName());

    @Around("execution(* com.training.AOPStuff.aopstuff.data.Dao1.retrieveSomething(..))")
    public void trackElapsedTime(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {

        //start time
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //allow execution of method
        try {
            proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //end time
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        System.out.println("message from within gthe aspect.");

        //LOGGER.info("Elapsed time for " + proceedingJoinPoint + " was " + elapsedTime);

    }

}
```

Comment: *causes the autowiring of the bean to return null*: what does that mean. What do you expect to happen when executing this code, and what happens instead, precisely?

Comment: Before you do anything else, fix your aspect's around advice first. It has return type `void`, but should have `Object` or `String`. It also has to return something matching the method(s) it intercepts, either directly the result of `proceed()` or some other compatible value.